# DataTable issues with span value

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I am doing export functions using DataTable for a report.
I have created the example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/hn2gcken/140/
I have user input value in W2, which also updates the value of 4Tax. I have created a hidden span tag to get those values when I insert. But the values are still not showing in the excel/PDF format.

Jquery

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            lengthChange: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "bPaginate": false,
            "paging":   false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info":     false,
            "searching": false,
            buttons: [  'excel', 'pdf']
        } );

        table.buttons().container()
            .appendTo( $('div.eight.column:eq(0)', table.table().container()) );

          $("#w2").keyup(function () {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0)
        {
            $("#w2-span").text($(this).val());
            $("#4tax-span").text($(this).val());
            $("#4tax").val($(this).val());
             $("#w2").attr('value', $(this).val())
        }
    });
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Elements with `display: none` might be inaccessible, have tried without to check if it works?

Comment: I have deleted 'display: none', still not working with that.

Comment: This link might help: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23965/jquery-datatables-tabletools-export-get-values-of-checkboxes-or-radio-items

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this,but seems complicated. I am looking into it :)